# Access instance properties of an Objective-C NSDocument subclass from Swift plugin?

Tags: objective-c, macos, plugins, swift3

The goal is to write a Swift plugin which can access public instance properties of an Objective-C NSDocument subclass.  The main application is in Objective-C.  The plugin is intended to be just Swift.

The main application has a public Objective-C document interface:

```
@interface ObjcNSDocument : NSDocument

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *markdown;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *html;

@end
```

A reasonable Swift counterpart would seem to be:

```
public class SwiftNSDocument: NSDocument {

    public var markdown: String = ""
    public var html: String = ""

}
```

The following Swift code retrieves the current NSDocument OK. However, the casting fails.

```
public func doFilter() {
    let dc = NSDocumentController.shared()
    if let document: NSDocument = dc.currentDocument {
        print("document.displayName = \(document.displayName)") // works OK
        let markdownSource = document as! SwiftNSDocument // FAIL: cannot cast as
    }
}
```

*While I'm asking this is general, my particular test case is to rewrite the [macdown-gistit](https://github.com/MacDownApp/macdown-gistit) Objective-C plugin as close as possible to pure Swift.*

Ideally, the solution would not require including any Objective-C code from the application. What is possible, even if not ideal?

**Additional Observation**

In the case of a working Objective-C plugin, the Application's NSDocument subclass `.h` file is *not included* in the plugin project.

Instead, the Objective-C plugin has only the single relevant property as an NSObject subclass.

```
@protocol MarkdownSource <NSObject>
@property (readonly) NSString *markdown;
@end
```

The NSDocument is then downcast as the NSObject subclass in Objective-C:

```
id<MarkdownSource> markdownSource = (id)document;
NSString *markdown = markdownSource.markdown;
```

Theoretically, one would think that something similar might work in Swift like

```
public class MarkdownSource: NSObject {
    public var markdown: String = ""
}
```

where `id` in Object-C would be a Swift `Any`. I've tried various downcastings were like such as:

```
 let markdownSource: MarkdownSource = (nsdocument as Any) as MarkdownSource
 let markdown: String = markdownSource.markdown
```

I have not, so far, been able to downcast an NSDocument subclass to any NSObject subclass with just the one desired property in Swift.

Comment: The cast fails because the type of the document is `ObjcNSDocument`, not `SwiftNSDocument`. At the moment, there is no facility in Swift to provide a Swift class that an Objective-C class would bridge to, or vice versa. You're going to have to include the declaration of the Objective-C class somewhere in the plugin (by including the header, or otherwise).

Comment: What is the goal here of trying to go Swift-only?

Comment: @itai-ferber Why Swift-only goal? to know what Objective-C is minimally needed and to write new code in Swift.

Comment: @itai-ferber I was curious if there might be some casting bridge mechanism from an Object-C subclass to a Swift subclass with the same members and the same base class.  It also appears that Swift will not downcast in a way similar to the Objective-C downcast.  See related detail added to question.

Comment: The cast that you're doing in Objective-C happens to work, but for the wrong reason. It's technically not a valid cast, since your Objective-C class doesn't actually conform to the `MarkdownSource` protocol; it works because Objective-C is unsafe in that way, and just dynamic enough — getting `markdownSource.markdown` translates to `[markdownSource markdown]`, which `document` happens to respond to, so it works. If I do `((id<MarkdownSource>)someRandomObject).markdown`, the cast will blindly succeed but the method call will fail.

Comment: Swift does not allow you to make these invalid casts as it will only allow you to make method calls that it can statically guarantee (as much as possible) that they will succeed. (Yes, you can use the Objective-C runtime to do certain things, but that eschews static safety.) **tl;dr:** casting in this way is invalid, so Swift will not let you do it.

Comment: You have two main options here: import the Objective-C header (which I see no reason not to — you're not actually writing any Objective-C, just exposing the interface to Swift so it has a guarantee that the type exists so you can use it), or make dynamic calls with `performSelector()`. The second option is not as safe, but will work as long as you have a guarantee that the object you're working with has the selector you need. You will not be able to avoid Objective-C entirely here; you will need to interface either statically, or at runtime.